# how to compile cscope with quickfix

Tags: vim, cscope

In my .vimrc , I added set `cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-`,but when I use cscope command in my vim, the quick window would not appear automatically.

I read the help doc from vim about cscope, and it tell me to use `"cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-"` I have to compile cscope with  +quickfix feature.

now my question is how to compile cscope with the +quickfix feathre

Comment: You can use `:version` to determine what you have installed. Or you can do `:echo has('cscope')` which will return 1 if vim is complied with cscope support. Also the `'cscopequickfix'` settings does not automatically open the quickfix list. As far as I know nothing will do that automatically. See `:h csqf` for more information. To open the quickfix window use `:cope` or `:cw`.

Comment: You don't compile "cscope with the +quickfix feature", you compile Vim with the +quickfix feature. What OS do you use? Can you post the output of `$ vim --version`?

Comment: I know what you mean Mr romain.And I'm shure I comiled vim with quickfix and the quickfix can work perfectly with my vim.   Now I wonder If I could scan all the results in a quickfix window right after I input a cscope command.  For eg:I type :'cs find c vim_strsave' , and a quickfix window appear telling me all the files invoke the vim_strvae method